# Linux based navigation software not working properly after using script (Audi MMI 3g HIGH)

Tags: linux, sh, ksh

I used this script to activate maps in my linux based navigation software. However, it failed.

```
#!/bin/ksh

#remount SD as rw
DRVS="sd0 sd1"
for i in $DRVS ; do
if [ -d /fs/$i ] ; then
if [ -e /fs/$i/upd ] ; then
mount -u /fs/$i
mount -u /fs/$i
SDCARD=/fs/$i
echo remount $SDCARD
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$SDCARD/utils
fi
fi
done

runtstamp=date +"%m/%d/%Y ""%T"

$SDCARD/utils/showScreen $SDCARD/screens/scriptStart.png
cd $SDCARD
/bin/mount -uw /mnt/efs-system
if test -a /sbin/mme-becker.sh ; then
# check if second install
XX=/usr/bin/grep acios_db.ini /sbin/mme-becker.sh
if [ ! -z "$XX" ]
then
# already installed - uninstall first!
$SDCARD/utils/showScreen $SDCARD/screens/error1.png
/bin/rm -f /tmp/copie_scr.sh
echo > /tmp/copie_scr.sh
exit 0
```

Now my navigation unit does not see Jukebox partiton, nor SD1 or SD2 or USB. I think I just have to remount or unmount partitons, but I am not sure about "-u" argument in commands. Would it be possible that SD card is unmounted and therefore I cannot activate any scripts or use SD slot at all?

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 0):

replace /fs/ with /mnt/ and add

```
/bin/rm -f /etc/mmelauncher.cfg
/bin/cp $SDCARD/mmelauncher.cfg /etc/mmelauncher.cfg
chmod 777 /etc/mmelauncher.cfg
```

to full script + add mmelauncher.cfg to SD card....